# r loop to merge data frames in a list by a specific column

Tags: r

I read my files on a list

```
data <- lapply(Sys.glob("*.txt"), read.table)
```

Each text file looks like this

```
> head(data[[1]])
    V1     V2     V3       V4 V5
1 chr1  28735  29810 CpG:_116  4
2 chr1 135124 135563  CpG:_30 15
3 chr1 327790 328229  CpG:_29  6
4 chr1 437151 438164  CpG:_84  6
5 chr1 449273 450544  CpG:_99  9
6 chr1 533219 534114  CpG:_94 32

> head(data[[2]])
    V1     V2     V3       V4 V5
1 chr1  28735  29810 CpG:_116  5
2 chr1 135124 135563  CpG:_30 16
3 chr1 327790 328229  CpG:_29 16
4 chr1 437151 438164  CpG:_84 11
5 chr1 449273 450544  CpG:_99 16
6 chr1 533219 534114  CpG:_94 38
```

The columns V1-V4 in each text file are the same. I want to merge the files in to one, according to column V4, while keeping V1-V3. The code I found was append on row, how to append on column instead?

```
V1   V2   V3   V4   V5_1   V5_2   V5_3   V5_4   ...   V5_50
```

**Question solved!**

```
data <- lapply(Sys.glob("*.txt"), read.table)
df <- dplyr::bind_cols(data)
df1 <- df[,c(1:4,seq(5, 250, by = 5))]
```

Comment: What do you mean merge by column V4, when you also mention that V1-V4 are same across all files? Can you provide view of at least one another dataset that you want to join? `bind_rows()` or `bind_columns()` from `dplyr` maybe useful for you case, but can only be certain with more information on the problem.

Comment: V4 is a unique column. There might be some duplicates on V1-V3. Other datasets have all the same V1-V4. Column V5 is the one I want to extract from each dataset and merge.

Comment: I am not sure I got it right, but try dplyr::bind_cols(data) and see if it lets you achieve the outcome

Comment: @M_Shimal I got all five columns from each dataframe when I tried dplyr::bind_cols(data). But I only want V1-V4 shown once at the beginning, as I showed at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do with the information you provided. Note that I created another data frame based on your question's requirements:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
            ~V1,     ~V2,     ~V3,        ~V4,  ~V5,
         "chr1",  28735L,  29810L, "CpG:_116",   4L,
         "chr1", 135124L, 135563L,  "CpG:_30", 111L,
         "chr1", 327790L, 328229L,  "CpG:_29",  88L,
         "chr1", 437151L, 438164L,  "CpG:_84", 100L,
         "chr1", 449273L, 450544L,  "CpG:_99", 255L,
         "chr1", 533219L, 534114L,  "CpG:_94", 775L
         )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
            ~V1,     ~V2,     ~V3,        ~V4,  ~V5,
         "chr1",  28735L,  29810L, "CpG:_116",   7L,
         "chr1", 135124L, 135563L,  "CpG:_30",  35L,
         "chr1", 327790L, 328229L,  "CpG:_29",  66L,
         "chr1", 437151L, 438164L,  "CpG:_84", 313L,
         "chr1", 449273L, 450544L,  "CpG:_99", 433L,
         "chr1", 533219L, 534114L,  "CpG:_94", 553L
         )

df1 %>% 
  left_join(., select(df2, V4, V5), by = "V4", suffix = c("", "_2"))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   V1        V2     V3 V4          V5  V5_2
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>    <int> <int>
#> 1 chr1   28735  29810 CpG:_116     4     7
#> 2 chr1  135124 135563 CpG:_30    111    35
#> 3 chr1  327790 328229 CpG:_29     88    66
#> 4 chr1  437151 438164 CpG:_84    100   313
#> 5 chr1  449273 450544 CpG:_99    255   433
#> 6 chr1  533219 534114 CpG:_94    775   553
```

Having a real list, you can try `purrr::reduce`. The difficult part is dropping the unwanted columns. Here the example is with two data frames in a list, what facilitates things a little bit.

```r
library(purrr)

list <- list(df1, df2)

list %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "V4", suffix = c("", "_2")) %>% 
  select(-matches("^V._\\d"), matches("^V5"))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   V1        V2     V3 V4          V5  V5_2
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>    <int> <int>
#> 1 chr1   28735  29810 CpG:_116     4     7
#> 2 chr1  135124 135563 CpG:_30    111    35
#> 3 chr1  327790 328229 CpG:_29     88    66
#> 4 chr1  437151 438164 CpG:_84    100   313
#> 5 chr1  449273 450544 CpG:_99    255   433
#> 6 chr1  533219 534114 CpG:_94    775   553
```

I think we got it now:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
            ~V1,     ~V2,     ~V3,        ~V4,  ~V5,
         "chr1",  28735L,  29810L, "CpG:_116",   4L,
         "chr1", 135124L, 135563L,  "CpG:_30", 111L,
         "chr1", 327790L, 328229L,  "CpG:_29",  88L,
         "chr1", 437151L, 438164L,  "CpG:_84", 100L,
         "chr1", 449273L, 450544L,  "CpG:_99", 255L,
         "chr1", 533219L, 534114L,  "CpG:_94", 775L
         )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
            ~V1,     ~V2,     ~V3,        ~V4,  ~V5,
         "chr1",  28735L,  29810L, "CpG:_116",   7L,
         "chr1", 135124L, 135563L,  "CpG:_30",  35L,
         "chr1", 327790L, 328229L,  "CpG:_29",  66L,
         "chr1", 437151L, 438164L,  "CpG:_84", 313L,
         "chr1", 449273L, 450544L,  "CpG:_99", 433L,
         "chr1", 533219L, 534114L,  "CpG:_94", 553L
         )

df3 <- tibble::tribble(
            ~V1,     ~V2,     ~V3,        ~V4,  ~V5,
         "chr1",  28735L,  29810L, "CpG:_116",  12L,
         "chr1", 135124L, 135563L,  "CpG:_30",  54L,
         "chr1", 327790L, 328229L,  "CpG:_29",  64L,
         "chr1", 437151L, 438164L,  "CpG:_84", 123L,
         "chr1", 449273L, 450544L,  "CpG:_99",  92L,
         "chr1", 533219L, 534114L,  "CpG:_94", 223L
         )

list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

namelist <- c(sprintf("V5_%s", seq(1, length(list))))

list %>% 
  map2(., namelist, ~rename(.x, !!.y := V5)) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "V4", suffix = c("", "_2")) %>% 
  select(-matches("^V._\\d"), matches("^V5"))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   V1        V2     V3 V4        V5_1  V5_2  V5_3
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 chr1   28735  29810 CpG:_116     4     7    12
#> 2 chr1  135124 135563 CpG:_30    111    35    54
#> 3 chr1  327790 328229 CpG:_29     88    66    64
#> 4 chr1  437151 438164 CpG:_84    100   313   123
#> 5 chr1  449273 450544 CpG:_99    255   433    92
#> 6 chr1  533219 534114 CpG:_94    775   553   223
```

Comment: Cool. But I have too many data frames, e.g V5_1, V5_2, V5_3....V5_50. How to write a loop for them? data[[1]], data[[2]], data[[3]]  refer to the data frame in the list.

Comment: Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches, environment()) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: You did that with the code above or with your real data? How many data frames does your list have?

Comment: It worked when I use the code above. When I use my list (35 elements), it threw out the error. The only different of the two list is the number of element, 2 vs 35.

Comment: data %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "V4", suffix = c("", "_2")) %>% 
  select(-matches("^V._\\d"), matches("^V5"))

Comment: Still came out the same error: Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches, environment()) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: Well, my example has now three data frames in a list and it is working well. Maybe your data is not structured the same way as mine. As I don't have access to your data, I can't go any further on predicting it.

Comment: Thank you anyway.